Convergent Subsequences and Limits
Given the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined by $a_n = (-1)^n$.
Prove that if $\{a_{n_j}\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent subsequence, then $\lim_{j \to \infty} a_{n_j} = 1$ or $-1$
I know that the terms of every subsequence of ${a_n}$ are just 1 or (-1), so it seems obvious that every convergent subsequence will eventually be constant and equal to 1 or (-1). But I don't know how to formalize that mathematically. Can someone help me with the proof?
Thank you for your help!

Assume $a_{n_j}\to a.$ Then $1=a_{n_j}^2\to a^2.$ Therefore $a^2=1,$ i.e. $a=1$ or $a=-1.$
In this way you do not need to  use $\varepsilon-N$ method or  analysis of subsequences.

Neat! Maybe this is a standard "trick", but I don't recall seeing this before. If it is somewhat standard (i.e. can be found in some elementary real analysis texts), then this is a removable singularity in my basic real analysis awareness (i.e. a hole, but one that is easily filled in).

@DaveL.Renfro  Thanks. I do not think you can find it in texts. For me it was a natural step in order  to simplify things.
